# Should it be "street" or "streets" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice, singular-vs-plural

In this sentence, the difference is clear, I think:

> He put on his jacket and ventured into the street(s).

**street:** one specific street.

**streets:** the streets of that city/town.

In the following sentence, however, I'm not very sure. Both options seems correct to me:

> Let's wait until there are fewer people on the street(s).

Is there any difference? What option is more appropiate?

Comment: The distinction seems the same as the one you mention in the first part of the question. Are you talking about a specific street, or all the streets?

Comment: In my experience as a speaker of AmE, very little consideration is given to differentiating the two words when used as you have used them.   *Street* is often understood to mean *Streets*.  Both are acceptable.  I would interpret them both to mean *one or more streets*.   I would only try to differentiate if there was a reason I needed to communicate something that applies to a particular, *single* street instead of *many* streets.

Comment: @StuartF I'm not referring to any particular street.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a subtle difference in your two examples and I don't think they mean quite the same thing.  Street can be used literally to refer to a paved road.  Street can also be used to refer to particular things that that are outdoors or occur outdoors.  Here in the U.S. homeless people live on/in the street or streets.  You may say either.  They both mean out of doors or unsheltered.

If I say *He puts on his leather jacket and ventures into the street(s)*, I would generally be saying *...and ventures outdoors.*  This is different than saying *He went into the street and starting clearing downed trees from last night's storm*, which is a literal reference to a paved road.

When referring to literal, paved roads you will want to pay attention to the plural form.  *The street is covered in oil* is different from *The streets are covered in oil*.  When referring to outdoors you can use either street or streets. In that instance they mean the same.